# Can't reach controller from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller

I'm using SPA page as a view, and trying to send a request to my controller. I have 200 code but no data from controller. I guess that there is some problems with routing or I'm requesting wrong URL's.

As I thought the URL like

'localhost:5001/api/game', 
'localhost:5001/api/game/get'

should return Json value to view but it returns spa index page.

Controller.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class GameController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            return Json(new {test = "123"});
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Project
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
namespace project
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.
            GetConnectionString("project_db")));
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config => config.RootPath = "Project_front/build");
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors(builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa => {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "project_front";
            if(env.IsDevelopment()){
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript:"start");
            }
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: [You're missing a lot of details to help answer the quesiton](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion).  Please include all relevant information (javascript code trying to get the data etc).

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is you're using `app.UseMvc();` after the invocation of `UseSpa()` .

The `UseSpa()` is actually a catch-all middleware, as the the [dos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaapplicationbuilderextensions.usespa?view=aspnetcore-2.2) describes:

> *Handles all requests from this point in the middleware chain by returning the default page for the Single Page Application (SPA).*
>
> *This middleware should be placed late in the chain, so that other middleware for serving static files, MVC actions, etc., takes precedence.*

In short, **you should never enable this middleware before `UseMvc`**. **The order of middlewares matters**.

Also, it's good to map the routes when configuring MVC:

```
    ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    
    // enable the spa middleware to "catch-all" the requests that are not been processed by previous middlewares
    app.UseSpa(spa => {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "project_front";
        if(env.IsDevelopment()){
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript:"start");
        }
    });
```

Comment: So should I use routing in Startup.cs ? Documentation says that i can do it in controller's attribute like [Route("api/[controller].

Comment: @EvgenyShmarev RouteAttribute only applies for a single controller onetime. I suggest you should combine the two ways .